# iOS: Get URL Scheme of Application

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I need to start a project that gives you the `url-scheme` of the Application according to the bundle ID or any other unique ID. I am thinking of using the [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searchexamples), but I have not found any way yet.

I am wondering how those launcher Apps do this.

Any suggestions or ideas how to automatically fetch the `url-schemes`?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Not all apps have custom url schemes. If there are apps that launch other apps on iOS, these `other` apps must have their url schemes made public and documented (for example on their website). There is no way for an app to launch other, arbitral app, at least not on non-jailbroken devices.

Comment: I know that now all apps have custome url schemes. The Developer must define it. But isn't there a database for url-schemes. [Launch](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/launcher-mit-mitteilungszentrale-widget/id905099592?mt=8) for example has a huge file called `AppList.cromulent` but I can't open it because I don't know how I can read it (It is encrypted or encoded in some way). I can not just collect thousands and thousands of applications url-schemes.

Comment: Can you provide a documentation link that says that all apps need to provide custom url schemess? The app you linked has an explicit note at the bottom of its description saying that "only certain apps that can be launched by third party apps are supported". Are you mistaking `Universal App Links` for this? `Universal App Links` simply enables you to redirect from `https://yoursite.com` to your app, without a custom `yourapp://` scheme. But it is not required.

Comment: No, I am talking about url schemes. "only certain apps that can be launched by third party apps are supported" means, that not all apps have url schemes implemented, which is absolutly right, but I need to create of find a Database or a List of available url schemes of apps if this app has url schemes implemented. There once was a site called [handleOpenURL](http://www.handleOpenURL.com) but it does not exist anymore.

Comment: Yep, so why in your previous comment did you state that you "know that now **all** apps have custom url schemes. The Developer **must** define it." (emphasis mine)? But to the problem at hand : there is no ready database/solution to gather this schemes automatically AFAIK.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the "now" should be a "not". Ok, I guess I have to build the database myself. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGölzhäuser - did you ever find a solid solution for this?  I am trying to find a way to open a few other specific apps (from within my app), but most of them don't have any published deeplinks.  This is also specifically for iOS...I can open all the apps in Android with the package name, but not so with iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Download the app, then unzip it. search "CFBundleURLSchemes" from Info.plist.

The most difficult part is how to download so many app automatically from app store.